# Change PIN like would on an atm

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write an ATM simulation code to CHANGE PIN, what line of code do i add to prompt for 'CONFIRM NEW PIN' and if the pin mismatches, an error should be raised?

I can create a new pin with this code, but it won't prompt the user to confirm a new pin like it would when changing a pin on an atm.

```
def change_pin(self):
        try:
            self.pin = str(int(get.getpass("ENTER NEW PIN: ")))
            if len(self.pin) != 4:
                raise ValueError
            print("\n*********PIN SET SUCCESSFULLY*********")
            self.continue_or_exit() 
        except ValueError as e:
            print(str("\n************PIN MUST BE 4 DIGITS ************"))
            self.change_pin()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider utilizing a while loop:

```
class ATM:

  def __init__(self, initial_pin: str):
    """Initialize ATM with an initial PIN."""
    self.pin = initial_pin

  def change_pin(self) -> None:
    """Change the PIN and ask for confirmation."""
    while True:
      try:
        new_pin = str(int(input("ENTER NEW PIN: ")))
        if len(new_pin) != 4:
          raise ValueError("Error: Enter exactly 4 digits")
        confirm_pin = str(int(input("CONFIRM NEW PIN: ")))
        if new_pin != confirm_pin:
          raise ValueError("Error: PINs do not match.")
        self.pin = new_pin
        print("\n*********PIN SET SUCCESSFULLY*********\n")
        self.continue_or_exit()
        break
      except ValueError as e:
        print(f"\n************{e}************\n")

  def continue_or_exit(self) -> None:
    """Ask user to continue or exit."""
    choice = input("Continue? (y/n): ")
    if choice.lower() == 'y':
      self.change_pin()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  atm = ATM(initial_pin="1234")
  atm.change_pin()
```

**Example Usage:**

```
ENTER NEW PIN: asdf

************Error: Enter exactly 4 digits************

ENTER NEW PIN: 123a

************Error: Enter exactly 4 digits************

ENTER NEW PIN: 9873
CONFIRM NEW PIN: 9872

************Error: PINs do not match************

ENTER NEW PIN: 9873
CONFIRM NEW PIN: 9873

*********PIN SET SUCCESSFULLY*********

Continue? (y/n): n
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Sash Sinha. In your example:

ENTER NEW PIN: 9873
CONFIRM NEW PIN: 9872

The error message should have been ' PINs do not match'

Comment: Fixed take a look

Comment: Great! That helps a lot. Thanks.